# How to Include more sheets to write incremental number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using this function which works upon submitting the entry via Google Forms. Currently the below script is adding increment number to the `Sheet1 Last empty row`

I want to include `two more sheets` where same incremental number will be added `to last empty row`.

Column will be same where increment number is pasting that is Column A but `Sheet1` data starts from `Row2` and `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` Data starts from `row6`.

Your help will be much appreciated.

```
  function uPDATEiT() {

  var aiColumnName = 'A'; //Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3 same column
  var requieredColName = 'C' //it is just for Sheet1

      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var worksheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3')

  var aiColRange = worksheet.getRange(aiColumnName + '1:' + aiColumnName + '1000');
  var aiCol = aiColRange.getValues();
  var aiColIndex = aiColRange.getColumn();
  var reqCol = worksheet.getRange(requieredColName + '1:' + requieredColName + '1000').getValues();

  var maxSeq = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= aiCol.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(aiCol[i], 10) > maxSeq) { maxSeq = aiCol[i]; }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= aiCol.length; i++) {
    if (('' + reqCol[i]).length > 0 && ('' + aiCol[i]).length === 0) {
      maxSeq++;
      worksheet.getRange(i + 1, aiColIndex).setValue(maxSeq);


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3 will be dependent to each other? where they have the same number of sequence in column A (but the row start differs?) or are they completely dependent and will based the increment number on the data available on the specific sheet? And are you open on just using sheets formula rather than apps script in filling up the sequence number in column A (lets say if the row value in column c is not empty)?

Comment: Yes these are dependents on each other and they have same increment number but sheet2 and sheet3 are sorted sometimes its sequence will be changed but all of three sheets have same numbers. Yes the Row Start differently. No i already have tried Arrays formula when the data is sorted  A to Z or Z to A through any column Arrays skip or create error.

Comment: Can you share a sample sheet, and your expected output? I'm not sure how this sorting works in your other sheets

Comment: Yes please here is the attached sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ULcriRyioJT75U5yC79rtR66j6zyvqcciY_T7JC0qj8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula in `Sheet2!A4` and `Sheet3!A4`:

```
={"ID's";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B5:B<>"",vlookup(B5:B,{'Data Sheet (Sheet1)'!$B$2:$B,'Data Sheet (Sheet1)'!$A$2:$A},2,false),""))}
```

### What it does?

- Check if column B is not empty, then get the id from Sheet1 based on the matched name(column B) as a key in the [vlookup()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

### Output:

Original Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet 2 using the formula:

[image]

### Update

If you just want to append your `maxSeq` in Sheet2, you can use this:

**Code:**

```
function uPDATEiT() {

  var aiColumnName = 'A'; //Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3 same column
  var requieredColName = 'C' //it is just for Sheet1

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var worksheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data Sheet (Sheet1)')
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  Logger.log(worksheet)
  Logger.log(sheet2.getLastRow())
  var aiColRange = worksheet.getRange(aiColumnName + '1:' + aiColumnName + '1000');
  var aiCol = aiColRange.getValues();
  var aiColIndex = aiColRange.getColumn();
  var reqCol = worksheet.getRange(requieredColName + '1:' + requieredColName + '1000').getValues();

  var maxSeq = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= aiCol.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(aiCol[i], 10) > maxSeq) { maxSeq = aiCol[i]; }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= aiCol.length; i++) {
    if (('' + reqCol[i]).length > 0 && ('' + aiCol[i]).length === 0) {
      maxSeq++;
      worksheet.getRange(i + 1, aiColIndex).setValue(maxSeq);
      sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow()+1,aiColIndex).setValue(maxSeq);

    }
  }
}
```

- Get the last row in the sheet that contains data using [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()) , then increment it by 1.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is great solution but let me tell you one more thing the data which is available in Sheet2 and Sheet3 from Column B to onward are coming using vlookup by matching ID's from the Data Sheet. So whenever new ID will update using Google from, Array Vlookup will popup the data in column B to onward

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I just based my answer on the sample sheet data. I'm having trouble understanding your process since you mentioned the data was added to your Data Sheet using a form. Then you added a sequence id in your Data Sheet using a script. You mentioned the data in Sheet2 and Sheet3 comes from your Data Sheet using vlookup by matching the ID. Then you originally plan to just append the same sequence number in Sheet 2 and Sheet3. So ideally, shouldn't be your Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 will have the same data with the same order?

Comment: If you just want to append a number on the last row of Sheet2, please see the updated answer and let me know if it works from your side

Comment: Yes you are right. I do not know what is wrong the Increment number is being added into Data Sheet but not in Sheet2 ? using baove changes

Comment: Why it is adding the ID in Sheet2 into the last row instead of Last non empty cell

Comment: Here you can check it is adding the data to the end of the rows https://ibb.co/FX8MV9P @Ron M this is example picture from the original sheet

Comment: We increment the last non empty row by 1 so basically it should be the next empty row after a row with data. `sheet2.getLastRow()+ 1`. It seems you have hidden rows. let me check again

Comment: No there is no hidden row i just hided to show the picture

Comment: I got confused in the existing script that you have in the sample sheet. I just use your original script in this post. The updated answer is working from my side

Comment: thank you very much for being so kind i got there is problem with my sheet. Thank yyou very much

Comment: you're welcome.